# loading a state depending on local storage token property - stateProvider, ionic / angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController' 
      })
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController' 
      });
});
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

How can I add a condition to state provider to verify if localstorage.token exist. If yes go to home else go to login

Now, I am going all the time on login state and there (loginController) I verify if I have or not a token on localstorage. I'm not satisfied with my version... that's why I want to improve it

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting home as your default route and performing a redirect if there is no token. So this would be your default route:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

And you would redirect if there is no token. You can do that by watching for the $locationChangeStart event in your run block:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // check for the user's token and that we aren't going to the login view
    if(!localStorage.token && next.templateUrl != 'login.html'){
      // go to the login view
      $state.go('login');
    }
  }
})
```

This has the added benefit of restricting the user to the login view if they have not authenticated.

Comment: I tried something like that but in this case a not logged user will see first the homepage for a short time and only then is redirecting to login ...the .config() is first executing just then .run ()

Comment: @godzo101 I've worked around that behavior by leaving the splash screen up while the app loads and hiding it at the end of the run() code.

Answer (score 0):

In app.run you can add your logic; this will fire on page-load and on refresh.

```
.run(function ($state) {
  if(localStorage.token) $state.go('home');
  else $state.go('login');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for your answer. I don't think I can ... cause that's another problem ... app.config() is called before app.run(); So first time will load the template and the controller, just then the app.run().  Do you have other approach  ? :)

Comment: Right, yes... it will load up login and then move over to home. This is for users landing on the main page yes? You want them to go right in if they're auth'd, elsewise take them to the login page. You could create a holding page and do your routing logic in there?

Comment: I think another state is a solution but it can be frustrating for a user to see a white screen or how would that page look before getting in the app... I thought that is possible to do it in config()  or set something where I define the states

Comment: Have you tried putting the logic in your .config? Not sure if it'll work but worth a try...  if (auth) $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home"); else $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

Comment: I should try ... can be a solution :)